# getting consistent output from nmap using Python

Tags: python, nmap

I'm writing a Python script to detect network devices when they get plugged in. I'm using nmap. Unfortunately even though I'm not connecting/reconnecting hosts right now, nmap is reporting different number of hosts almost every loop. How do I get the same output every loop when hosts are not being disconnected/connected?

```
nmaps = []
nmaps_last_lines = []
import re
import os
while True:
    print "Scanning"
    if not nmaps:
        output = os.popen('sudo nmap --host-timeout 20s -sP 10.0.1.0/24 -oG -').read()
        nmaps_last_lines.append(output.split('\n')[-2])
        output = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+', output)
        nmaps.append(output)
    else:
        output = os.popen('sudo nmap --host-timeout 20s -sP 10.0.1.0/24 -oG -').read()
        nmaps_last_lines.append(output.split('\n')[-2])
        output = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+', output)
        nmaps.append(output)
        if set(output) != set(nmaps[-2]):

            #previous_output = set([i.strip() for i in nmaps[-2].split('\n')[1:-2]])
            #current_output = set([i.strip() for i in nmaps[-1].split('\n')[1:-2]])
            print "New equipment detected"
            print '\n'.join(list(set(output) - set(nmaps[-2])))
            print nmaps_last_lines[-1]
            print nmaps_last_lines[-2]
            #print "Current output"
            #print nmaps[-1].split('\n')
            #print current_output
            #print "Previous output"
            #print nmaps[-2].split('\n')
            #print previous_output
            #break
```

Scanning
Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.41
10.0.1.23

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:07:55 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 22.68 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:07:32 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 3.32 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:02 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 6.51 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:07:55 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 22.68 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.23
10.0.1.42

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:18 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 16.45 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:02 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 6.51 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.10

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:30 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 12.19 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:18 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 16.45 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.23

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:44 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 14.17 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:30 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 12.19 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:54 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (16 hosts up) scanned in 9.45 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:44 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 14.17 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.23
10.0.1.10
10.0.1.41
10.0.1.22
10.0.1.42

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:05 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (21 hosts up) scanned in 11.40 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:08:54 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (16 hosts up) scanned in 9.45 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:16 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 10.25 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:05 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (21 hosts up) scanned in 11.40 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.10

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:26 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 10.42 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:16 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 10.25 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.23
10.0.1.21

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:59 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 32.71 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:26 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 10.42 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.22

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:04 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 5.28 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:09:59 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 32.71 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.10
10.0.1.41
10.0.1.21
10.0.1.42

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:12 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (22 hosts up) scanned in 8.00 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:04 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (18 hosts up) scanned in 5.28 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:21 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 8.61 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:12 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (22 hosts up) scanned in 8.00 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.10
10.0.1.23

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:11:17 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (21 hosts up) scanned in 55.83 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:10:21 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 8.61 seconds

Scanning
Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:12:41 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 38.61 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:12:03 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (21 hosts up) scanned in 45.79 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected
10.0.1.23

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:12:52 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 11.05 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:12:41 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (20 hosts up) scanned in 38.61 seconds

Scanning
New equipment detected

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:13:00 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (16 hosts up) scanned in 7.39 seconds

## Nmap done at Sat Oct 26 00:12:52 2013 -- 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 11.05 seconds

Scanning

Comment: I'm going to bet that it's the host-timeout option and that nmap kind of sucks as a scanner in general. Best bet would be writing your own scanner or finding a more low-level solution.

Comment: Using the scanner Fing http://www.overlooksoft.com/ I also get inconsistent results.

Comment: Trying the scanner http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipscan/ also produced inconsistent output when repeatedly ran

Comment: You need to dig deeper. Is it one or two specific hosts that are flapping? What are their IP addresses? What are their mac addresses? This could be a variety of problems unrelated to the actual mapping. Are you scanning a /16 or a /32? Do they have their netmasks set correctly? Are they DHCP? Are they rebooting?